# Xcode 6 add a back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, back-button

I have been trying to figure out why the back button will not show. in my tableview (which is dynamically populated) i have

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //NSString *continent = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *myController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EditProfileController"];
    [self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:nil];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

this works find and i can open a view called EditProfileController. In my EditProfileController.m I have this

```
#import "EditProfileController.h"

@interface EditProfileController ()

@end


@implementation EditProfileController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(Back)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)Back
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // ios 6
}

@end
```

I expected to see a back button but nothing shows.

[image: Here is my storyboard]

Here is the storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace your settings view controller with a navigation controller. Then, put the settings view controller as root of the navigation controller. Finally, push the edit view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Select the settingsViewController goto Edit->embed in->navigation controller. And use protocols and delegates to pass the data to detail view